# RecyclerView update multiple locations

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

The notifyItemChanged method can only update one location at a time，and The notifyItemRangeChanged method can only update consecutive positions,How can I update multiple separate locations at once?

Comment: Only you can is call notifyItemChanged mutiple times with seperate index

Answer (score 0):

There is a really useful recyclerView item update blog here. Check it and use appropriate solution for your scenario. https://medium.com/@suragch/updating-data-in-an-android-recyclerview-842e56adbfd8

Answer (score 0):

You can use **notifyItemRangeChange** when updating the **data from and to** in the position adapter

This example shows how to use it:

```
       List<String> data;
             data = new ArrayList<>();
            //Add Anything list data

             void AddMultipleItems() {

                ArrayList<String> fruits = new ArrayList<>();

                fruits.add("Apple");
                fruits.add("orange");
                fruits.add("banana");
                int fruitsIndex = 2;
                data.addAll(insertIndex, fruits );
                adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(insertIndex, fruits.size());
            }
```

Use this method if you have multiple data changed but not all , those changed data also are in cluster so that you can say from 25th to 30th index data are changed .

> If all data are changed call :

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**Notes:**
If you use **notifyDataSetChanged()**, then no animation will be performed. This can also be an expensive operation, so it is not recommended to use **notifyDataSetChanged()** if you are only updating a single item or a range of items.

Check out [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html) if you are making large or complex changes to a list.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to update only two items, i.e., new and old item.
I put the old items position in a variable and update both new and old positions as below,

```
class FontAdapter(
private var curSelectedFontSource: Int
) : ListAdapter<FontItem, FontAdapter.MyViewHolder>(Companion) {

private var oldItemPos = -1

// other implementations

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val isSelected = getItem(position).fontSource == 
curSelectedFontSource
    if (isSelected) {
        oldItemPos = position
    }
    holder.binding.root.setOnClickListener {
        notifyItemChanged(position)
        notifyItemChanged(oldItemPos)
    }
  }
}
```